# Prove that a subgroup which contains half of all elements is a normal subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

I have been going through some material on elementary group theory ([Group Theory for Physicists, Christoph Ludeling](http://www.th.physik.uni-bonn.de/nilles/people/luedeling/grouptheory/data/grouptheorynotes.pdf)) and in one place it states:

*A subgroup which contains half of all elements, i.e. for which $|G|=2|H|$, is a normal subgroup.*

Where a subgroup $H\subset G$ is called a normal subgroup if $gHg^{-1}=H~\forall g\in G$.
How would I go about proving this? Sorry if the answer exists somewhere, but I tried searching and could not find it.

Comment: You will find it if you search for «subgroups of index 2»

Comment: Thanks for that, that was what exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two left cosets of $H$ are $H$ and $G\setminus H$, and the two right cosets of $H$ are also $H$ and $G\setminus H$. Clearly $xH=Hx$ for every $x\in H$, and if $x\in G\setminus H$, then $xH=G\setminus H=Hx$ as well. Thus, $xH=Hx$ for each $x\in G$, and $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Stylistic complaint: the $x$ you fixed in the the first part of the first sentence is not used until the second sentence :-)

Comment: @Mariano: Yes, that’s pretty horrible. It was left over from an earlier version; I just forgot that it was there when I changed the first sentence.

Comment: Thank-you for that, much appreciated. I will accept your answer in four minutes when it lets me.

Comment: @Andrew: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 8):

Not as slick but perhaps more direct (as given in Rotman):

> It suffices to prove that if $h \in H$, then the conjugate
>    $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for every $g \in G$.  If $g \in H$, then $ghg^{-1}\in
>  H$, because $H$ is a subgroup.  If $g \notin H$, then $g = ah_0$,
>    where $h_0\in H$ (for $G = H \cup aH$).  If $ghg^{-1} \in H$, we are
>    done.  Otherwise, $ghg^{-1} = ah_1$ for some $h_1\in H$.  But $ah_1 =
>  ghg^{-1} = ah_0hh_0^{-1}a^{-1}$.  Cancel $a$ to obtain $h_1 =
>  h_0hh_0^{-1}a^{-1}$, contradicting $a \notin H$.

This was the proof I came up with before reading the slick proof in the text I was reading, seeing it appear in Rotman later made me feel less silly.

Comment: Thanks for that, it is always useful to see different ways of looking at things.